# Paypal ios SDK not clearing previously used credit cards even after call to [PayPalMobile clearAllUserData]

Tags: ios, paypal, card.io

I'm integrating Paypal ios SDK version 2.1 into my app but have run into a problem.
The SDK seems to keep past payment cards in memory even though i call `[PayPalMobile clearAllUserData]` after the payment has been completed.

```
@interface AirliftCartViewController : AirliftViewController <AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, AirliftCartTotalsChangeDelegate, PayPalPaymentDelegate>
    @property (strong) AVCaptureSession * captureSession;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *cameraPreview;
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PayPalConfiguration *payPalConfiguration;
    - (IBAction)initiateCreditCardCheckout:(id)sender;
@end
...
@implementation AirliftCartViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil timeout:(NSUInteger)timeoutInSeconds screenName:(NSString *)screenName
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil timeout:timeoutInSeconds screenName:@"AirliftCartView"];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.payPalConfiguration = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
        self.payPalConfiguration.rememberUser = NO;
    }

    return self;
}



- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController
{
    NSLog(@"payment cancelled!");
    // The payment was canceled; dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [paymentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // clear all paypal user information
        [PayPalMobile clearAllUserData];
    }];
}

- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment
{
    NSLog(@"Payment was successful");
    // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment.
    [self verifyCompletedPayment:completedPayment];

    // Dismiss the PayPalPaymentViewController.
    [paymentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    // clear all paypal user information
    [PayPalMobile clearAllUserData];

    // emptycart
    [self.cartController emptyCart];

    // reset metadata
    [self.metaDataFound removeAllObjects];

}

- (IBAction)initiateCheckout:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"checkout requested!");
    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox];

    // present paypal payment
    PayPalPaymentViewController * payPalVC = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc]
                                          initWithPayment:[self.cartController getPayPalPaymentFromCart]
                                          configuration:self.payPalConfiguration delegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:payPalVC animated:YES completion:^{
        [self.captureSession stopRunning];
        [self.cameraPreview removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}


@end
```

I present the PayPalPaymentViewController like this (so there's no strong reference to it that i can tell)

Its not acceptable that any card information is kept retained for my app, any ideas anyone?

Edit: Adding user steps as requested:

- the user selects products to buy and then clicks on checkout button which has initiateCheckout as its Action.
- this brings up the paypalpaymentviewcpntroller which shows the previously used card as the only payment option (the first time I launch the controller provides a choice of either logging into paypal or using a card)

Edit 2: Added property declarations for `captureSession` and `cameraPreview` and expanded `init` definition

Edit 3: Added screenshots

[image: initial checkout]
[image: second checkout]

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

A few questions:

(1) What's going on with your `captureSession` and `cameraPreview`?

(2) Could you please provide a series of specific steps, from the user's perspective, that reproduce your problem?

(3) What is the indication that the SDK is keeping card data in memory?

(4) Which version of the SDK are you running? I'm guessing that it's the one of the most recent versions, 2.1.5 or 2.1.6?

*** EDIT (1 August 2014): The originally described bug has been fixed in our [latest release](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases). ***

Comment: Hi Dave, answers to your questions:(1) captureSession is an AVCaptureSession that I use for barcode scanning. Camerapreview is a preview layer view associated with the session. (2) I edited my question to include steps (3) when I present the paymentviewcontroller in initiateCheckout the previously used card shows up on the first screen, I can take a screenshot if you'd like. (4) the header says 2.1, I copied the library a few months back. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SandeepPhadke thanks! This does look like a bug in the SDK. We'll have an updated version with a fix, probably within a few days.

Comment: @SandeepPhadke following up on the comment by @Romk1n... Even though there is a bug in `clearAllUserData` that I will be fixing, in my tests setting `payPalConfiguration.rememberUser` to `NO` does eliminate the problem. Could you double-check your flow to confirm that `payPalConfiguration.rememberUser` is still `NO` when you create and present the `PayPalPaymentViewController`? If it is, then you should not need to call `clearAllUserData` at all.

Comment: Also, please download and use the current version of the SDK. The headers should show `2.1.6` as the version number.

Comment: ok i'll upgrade the SDK and take a look, right now I call `payPalConfiguration.rememberUser = NO` in the class init function, maybe I should move it to `viewDidLoad` and see if that affects the behavior

Comment: I upgraded the SDK and moved my `alloc` and `init` for `PayPalConfiguration` to `viewDidLoad` and you're right, I do not see the card being shown again! One related question does setting `PaypalConfiguration.rememberUser` to `NO` or calling `[PayPalMobile clearAllUserData]` affect if the card is stored in the PayPal Vault or not? I need the card to be stored to look it up if used again.

Comment: Yes, either of those approaches will prevent the card from being stored in the Vault. It sounds like your use case is one that we had not considered. Why do you want to not remember the card info locally, but still want it in the Vault?

Comment: my app runs in a self service checkout kiosk where a user may or may not have an account with us, if they do I want to use the stored cored, if not I want to use a "one-time" card. I also encourage "one time" users to create an account on our site & credit them for their past transactions, so when I "convert" a user to a user with an account I want to bind their payment information & past transactions with their account by asking for the last 4 digits of their credit card & validating the email address. I can just ask for the full card details again but the vault would  helped.

Comment: Just to add I plan on using a stored card from our service along with the paypal REST api and not through the app..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58193/discussion-between-dave-goldman-and-sandeep-phadke).

Answer (score 0):

You can also set remeberUser = NO in PayPalConfiguration https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/PayPalMobile/PayPalConfiguration.h#L57 so SDK doesn't even try to save anything.

Comment: Yeah I set rememberUser to NO in init for my viewcontroller.